# Why can't I assign an 'object' datatype to a Pandas series that contains all 'object' type entries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I want to fill some missing data in the titanic data set with the most common value, namely 'S':

```
# This does not work:     
df.loc[df.Embarked.isnull(), 'Embarked'] = df.Embarked.mode()

# But this does work: 
df.loc[df.Embarked.isnull(), 'Embarked'] = 'S'

# And this works too:   
df.loc[df.Embarked.isnull(), 'Embarked'] = str(df.Embarked.mode())
```

I thought it might have to do with mismatched datatypes, so I checked this:

```
df.Embarked.mode()
>>> 
0    S
dtype: object
```

So the mode is returned as an object. Checking the datatype of the Embarked column, we see it also contains all objects:

```
df.Embarked
>>> 
PassengerId
1       S
2       C
3       S
4       S
5       S
       ..
1305    S
1306    C
1307    S
1308    S
1309    C
Name: Embarked, Length: 1309, dtype: object
```

Now that I've figured out what does work, and it isn't that hard to implement, I'm just curious why the obvious (for me) solution didn't work?

Comment: `df.loc[df.Embarked.isnull(), 'Embarked']  = df.Embarked.mode()[0]`?

Comment: `object` is the type of the element in the column (pandas calls `str` an `object`). if you did `type(df.Embarked.mode())` you would see it is a `Series` in case you have more than one mode (i.e. no duplicates). You just need the value of the first element, so what @QuangHoang said will work.

Comment: @E.Bassett, interesting that typecasting the series to a string worked as well. And thank you Quang Hoang. If either of you that want to expand to an answer, I'll happily give you some internet cred. Either way, thank you.

Comment: I'm surprised the cast worked and `str(df.Embarked.mode())` doesn't give you something like `'0    PassengerId\ndtype: object'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some background:
`object` is the type of the element in the column (pandas calls `str` an `object`). if you did `type(df.Embarked.mode())` you would see it is a `Series` in case you have more than one mode (i.e. no duplicates).

What you want:
`df.loc[df.Embarked.isnull(), 'Embarked'] = df.Embarked.mode()[0]`